# Can't connect mongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb

I cant connect to mongoDB atlas using my app or even compass, I receive that error

connection 11 to cluster0-shard-00-02-uypd6.mongodb.net:27017 closed

That is the first time I try to connect from this local, maybe a LAN problem? at house everthing connects fine

Comment: Did you add IP in you Mongon Security ?

Comment: Thanks, I worked for so long in the same place, forgot about that, thank you!

Comment: Im Answering the Question please accept it as it will help others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please add IP in you Mongo Security list to allow your IP to access Mongo.

- Help :)